# lightning:spinner in slds-scrollable scrolls out of view

Tags: lightning-aura-components, scrolling, modal

I am displaying a long scrollable content in a modal

```
<c:strike_modal aura:id="filterModal" title="Filter volumes" primaryButtonLabel="Ok" secondaryButtonLabel="Cancel" showHeader="true" showFooter="true" showModal="false">
    <div class="slds-scrollable slds-is-relative">
        <lightning:spinner aura:id="spinner" class="slds-hide" />
        ...
        much content
        ...
    </div>
</c:strike_modal>
```

and my problem is that the spinner is not shown when the user scrolls to the bottom of the modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Martin Lezer's answer is not what you're looking for, you can just put the `lightning:spinnner` outside of the `<div class="slds-is-relative">`. The spinner will be centered and the user will not be able to scroll.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the spinner to follow the user's scroll, you can modify the position of the spinner.

By default, Lightning add the spinner to the center of the page. Using a `div` with the `slds-spinner` class with the following style:

```
.slds-spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}
```

To make this div follow the scroll, you can override this style and set the position to fixed using:

```
.THIS .slds-spinner {
    position: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Also you can use `<lightning:spinner class="slds-is-fixed"/>` if you don't want to add custom css.

Comment: @MichalV This is useful, Thank you!